# Where can I find the values used in Android themes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

Does anyone know how I can find out what values are set in different Android themes? I know how to find the names of themes in the Graphical Layout view for a layout resource (Theme.Black, Theme.Light, Theme.Holo.Light, etc).

I want to find out the margins, color values, padding, and all that stuff for the different themes so I can make my app look consistent across devices whether they have a particular theme available or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information regarding the theme from the

```
@android:style/
```

So please Do it in your style.xml  in value directory and you will get the default value of the style.

You can also add your custom style for any behaviour like theme or textAppearance or anything you want.

Also refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Just refer it and you will get that values.

Hope it will help you.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to find the themes in certain device, you should get the source code of this device or decompile the `framework-res.apk` can also get `styles.xml` and `themes.xml` file. A lot of devices have changed the default themes, so if you want to make your app looks the same in different devices, the best way i think is to add `android:theme` in your AndroidManifest and refer to a self-build theme which does not inherit the system theme.